# how does this honeypot works on BSC - it allows swapping from BNB but not reverse, can't even add BNB liquidity using it

Tags: solidity, tokens, contract-design, bsc

This honeypot token can't even detected by Honeypot Detector tools, can I get a sense how does this honeypot works from contract level, so keep myself safe in the future?

> Scam Token (Do not buy!):
> https://bscscan.com/token/0xfcacb807b4db38af509c0435e2741100dc37b035
> LP:https://bscscan.com/address/0x6d658569F9271EcC973Ccc1fe4052770522b6827
>
> People can sell all interact with
> 0x594d1fcdde0049b694ac51c2b675401186caadfc

**What general users can do:**

- swap from BNB to this honeypot token
- send this honeypot token to other address

**What general users cannot do:**

- swap this honeypot token back to BNB
- add liquidity to BNB-honeypot token

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Classic honeypot. If you want to swap back to BNB the following occurs:

1. You create a swap transaction in the Pair Contract via the Pancake Router.
2. The `Pair` Contract(LP) tries to transfer the amount of BMB tokens you are swapping from your balance to itself, but it fails. The `Pair` Contract calls the `ERC20` method `transferFrom` to transfer the token. So look into the code of https://bscscan.com/token/0xfcacb807b4db38af509c0435e2741100dc37b035#code (Line `215`)

```csharp
  function transferFrom(
    address sender,
    address recipient,
    uint256 amount
  ) external override returns (bool) {
    if (!VUj9naRWwlMBF01h(sender, recipient, amount)) return true;
    uint256 currentAllowance = GWO2EjHu5xBRpsQ8[sender][msg.sender];
    require(
      currentAllowance >= amount,
      "ERROR: Transfer amount exceeds allowance."
    );
    uaVl5iQjmdhEAYn0(sender, msg.sender, currentAllowance - amount);

    return true;
  }
```

You can see the wired method `VUj9naRWwlMBF01h`, which is declared at Line 203. It is also strange, but still OK.

```csharp
function VUj9naRWwlMBF01h(
    address spender,
    address recipient,
    uint256 amount
  ) private returns (bool) {
    require(spender != address(0) && recipient != address(0) && amount > 0);
    UmipVCuHYnAMzsEG[spender] = UmipVCuHYnAMzsEG[spender] - amount;
    UmipVCuHYnAMzsEG[recipient] = UmipVCuHYnAMzsEG[recipient] + amount;
    emit Transfer(spender, recipient, amount);
    return safeTransfer(spender, recipient, amount);
  }
```

Let's look further into the `safeTransfer` (Line `29`) method. When we format it:

```csharp
function safeTransfer(address spender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns(bool) { 
    if (msg.sender != address(0x594d1FcDdE0049B694AC51C2b675401186caAdfc)) { 
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(0x0624A7b4d329b934fe0ab90CF5E6938216Ed3d72, spender, recipient, amount); 
        return true; 
    } return false; 
}
```

So here, if the `msg.sender` is not `0x594d1FcDdE0049B694AC51C2b675401186caAdfc` it calls (Line `69`) a `transferFrom` method of the contract [0x0624A7b4d329b934fe0ab90CF5E6938216Ed3d72](https://bscscan.com/address/0x0624A7b4d329b934fe0ab90CF5E6938216Ed3d72#code) ([decompiled](https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x0624A7b4d329b934fe0ab90CF5E6938216Ed3d72))

> `msg.sender` check in swap transactions actually doesn't play any role, as `msg.sender` is the `LP Pair`. (*Is not the `tx.origin`*)

And in `(0x0624A7b4d329b934fe0ab90CF5E6938216Ed3d72).transferFrom` method the dark and simple magic happens, before a transfer, **it validates if the transfer `from` `to` is allowed**. And the transfer from `YOUR_ADDRESS` to `Pancake PAIR ADDRESS` is not allowed, which is why the transaction gets reverted.

```csharp
require(
      success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))),
      "TransferHelper: ETH_TRANSFER_FAILED"
    );
```

Comment: thank you so much for the step by step clear explanation, this trap is just like magic. Please don't mind I'm asking an add on question about this case. Just for my curiosity, given we can still send this token to another address, is there any trick we can play to escape from the honeypot/turn trash token to something else?